# What is preferable way of managing EC2 instances when a unit work is needed as soon as possible?

Tags: amazon-ec2

Are there performance advantages of ordering stop and start commands on an instance against using an image to run and terminate new instance?

Does volume size effect performance of start - stop less than run - terminate?

Should I use star/stop when disk size is 16 - 64 GB or using terminate/run is better?

Comment: Why not use something like AWS Batch or AWS Lambda?

Comment: Because I don't know where to start for planning a future-proof on-demand compute resource that has quickest response timing such that user clicks on a button on a web site and 2 seconds later an instance delivers results, with optimal programming complexity and cloud costs.

Comment: Mm. Before we think about the *solution*, what is your *problem*?

Comment: You might have better luck with aws lambda. Firecracker is quite fast, though I haven't tested the latency of spinups, something like ~125ms for a microvm spinup. I know that people use it for serverless architectures to respond to requests using AWS api gateway -- might be worth looking into. The lambda instance has to run under 5 min from what I remember, I hope this helps!

Comment: Firecracker looks good. Reading it now. Thank you.